# ISNULL or COALESCE not working with joining and with pivot operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have tried to make a datatable with joining more than 2 tables but however my return dataset has a null value .I want to make return it 0 and used both ISNULL and COALESCE but both didnt work with me since im using Pivot operation.
Following is my sql query.

```
SELECT MetricHeader,[16],[17],[18],[22],[23],[24],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]
FROM (
SELECT 'P1' as MetricHeader,co.OptionId as CrossbreakHeader,
ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal,k.Response),0) as KpiResponse
FROM
( 
SELECT PanelistId,ProjectId FROM zcachetable_Edm_Sampling_1_5  
INTERSECT
SELECT PanelistId,ProjectId FROM zcachetable_Edm_Sampling_1_5  
INTERSECT
SELECT PanelistId,ProjectId FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_51 as d
WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51)  
INTERSECT
SELECT PanelistId,ProjectId FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_54 as d
WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (16,17,18,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30)
INTERSECT
SELECT PanelistId,ProjectId FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_55 as d
WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (19,20,21,31,32,33,34,35)
) f
INNER JOIN zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_54 cc ON cc.PanelistId = f.PanelistId AND f.ProjectId=cc.ProjectId
INNER JOIN n1 co ON ((cc.ResponseCode IS NOT NULL AND cc.ResponseCode = co.OptionId))
INNER JOIN zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_55_KPIScore k ON cc.PanelistId=k.PanelistId AND cc.ProjectId=k.ProjectId
) sq
PIVOT
(
AVG(KpiResponse)
FOR sq.CrossbreakHeader IN ([16],[17],[18],[22],[23],[24],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])
) AS pt
```

[image]

I have attached the image of the result set and it has null value for column value 30.I want to make it as 0 and i tried every option on Internet couldn't find a solution.I ll be so grateful you guys can suggest me a way to do that.

Comment: What database are you using ? Please be specific and don't tag all

Comment: You should also post the table schema & sample data.

Comment: Im using SQL server

Comment: I have removed the wrong tag

Comment: This `ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal,k.Response),0)` won't do, but @Squirrel gave you the tip to fix this. `ISNULL` that you already have happens **before** pivoting. And for `CrossbreakHeader = '30'` there are no rows, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` to handle the NULL value

example, your query

```
ISNULL ( [30], 0)
```

Comment: I cant try any thing... Just told Test Cases..!!

Answer (score 0):

> `@Squirrel` gave you the tip to fix this. `ISNULL` that you already have happens before pivoting. And for `CrossbreakHeader = '30'` there are no rows, that's it.

– Ivan Starostin

```
create table #null ( i int, name varchar(10))

insert #null values
(1,'One'),(2,'Two'),(3,'Three'),(4,'Four'),(null,'Five')

select one, five, six from ( -- Here, NULL for 'six'
 select name, ISNULL(i, 0) i from #null
) n
pivot
(
 sum(i) for name in (one, five, six)  -- I cant insert 'six'
)p
```

Answer (score 0):

When pivoting it is all too easy to focus on that, but in truth it is the final select clause where you need to use COALESE or ISNULL, like this:

```
SELECT
    MetricHeader
  , COALESCE([16], 0) AS [16]
  , COALESCE([17], 0) AS [17]
  , COALESCE([18], 0) AS [18]
  , COALESCE([22], 0) AS [22]
  , COALESCE([23], 0) AS [23]
  , COALESCE([24], 0) AS [24]
  , COALESCE([26], 0) AS [26]
  , COALESCE([27], 0) AS [27]
  , COALESCE([28], 0) AS [28]
  , COALESCE([29], 0) AS [29]
  , COALESCE([30], 0) AS [30]
FROM (
    SELECT
        'P1'                                    AS metricheader
      , co.OptionId                             AS crossbreakheader
      , ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal, k.Response), 0) AS kpiresponse
    FROM (
        SELECT
            PanelistId
          , ProjectId
        FROM zcachetable_Edm_Sampling_1_5

        INTERSECT

        SELECT
            PanelistId
          , ProjectId
        FROM zcachetable_Edm_Sampling_1_5

        INTERSECT

        SELECT
            PanelistId
          , ProjectId
        FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_51 AS d
        WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51)

        INTERSECT

        SELECT
            PanelistId
          , ProjectId
        FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_54 AS d
        WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)

        INTERSECT

        SELECT
            PanelistId
          , ProjectId
        FROM zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_55 AS d
        WHERE d.ResponseCode IN (19, 20, 21, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
    ) f
    INNER JOIN zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_54 cc ON cc.PanelistId = f.PanelistId
        AND f.ProjectId = cc.ProjectId
    INNER JOIN n1 co ON ((cc.ResponseCode IS NOT NULL
        AND cc.ResponseCode = co.OptionId))
    INNER JOIN zcachetable_Edm_Responses_1_17_55_KPIScore k ON cc.PanelistId = k.PanelistId
        AND cc.ProjectId = k.ProjectId
    ) sq
PIVOT
    (
    AVG(KpiResponse)
    FOR sq.CrossbreakHeader IN ([16], [17], [18], [22], [23], [24], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30])
    ) AS pt
```

Comment: A true pleasure! I can vividly remember having the exact same issue first time I used pivot.